# Should we use _In_ instead of __in?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, annotations

I read sal.h, which is in VS2010, today.
I was a little surprised.

```
// This section contains the deprecated annotations
|------------|------------|---------|--------|----------|----------|---------------|
|   Level    |   Usage    |  Size   | Output | NullTerm | Optional |  Parameters   |
|------------|------------|---------|--------|----------|----------|---------------|
| <>         | <>         | <>      | <>     | _z       | <>       | <>            |
| _deref     | _in        | _ecount | _full  | _nz      | _opt     | (size)        |
| _deref_opt | _out       | _bcount | _part  |          |          | (size,length) |
|            | _inout     |         |        |          |          |               |
|            |            |         |        |          |          |               |
|------------|------------|---------|--------|----------|----------|---------------|
```

I always used these annotations.
I can't believe that they are deprecated. Is it true?
If so, why?
Should we use following annotations from now on? -It's not familiar to me :(

```
|--------------|----------|----------------|-----------------------------|
|   Usage      | Nullness | ZeroTerminated |  Extent                     |
|--------------|----------|----------------|-----------------------------|
| _In_         | <>       | <>             | <>                          |
| _Out_        | opt_     | z_             | [byte]cap_[c_|x_]( size )   |
| _Inout_      |          |                | [byte]count_[c_|x_]( size ) |
| _Deref_out_  |          |                | ptrdiff_cap_( ptr )         |
|--------------|          |                | ptrdiff_count_( ptr )       |
| _Ret_        |          |                |                             |
| _Deref_ret_  |          |                |                             |
|--------------|          |                |                             |
| _Pre_        |          |                |                             |
| _Post_       |          |                |                             |
| _Deref_pre_  |          |                |                             |
| _Deref_post_ |          |                |                             |
|--------------|----------|----------------|-----------------------------|
```

By the way, SAL tag doesn't exist in SO.
Please make it, if you could.

Comment: Eh? This looks like SQL... what language are you referring to? Windows, Visual Studio, and Microsoft aren't languages. I'd guess MS SQL, but `.h` indicates C or C++.

Comment: SAL is not a language. It's an annotation for c/c++.

Comment: Mark: SAL is the Source-code Annotation Language (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402(VS.100).aspx) which is used to annotate parameters in C/C++ functions so the compiler and other tools can give better warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you should getting used to the new "attribute" SAL format, see the comment in red in the middle of this post:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314053935/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/19/602077.aspx)

Comment: Another link with a full explanation and examples: [A Declspec SAL to Attribute SAL Rosetta Stone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2009/06/11/a-declspec-sal-to-attribute-sal-rosetta-stone/)