# What is _In_ in C++?

Tags: c++, c, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I have searched this up rather a lot, but come up with no helpful results.

I am currently trying to program simple DirextX game for Windows 8 Metro, and have come across `_In_` rather a lot. I'm just wondering what it is.

Also, I have seen a lot of the use of `^` as the pointer `*` which I found odd. On top of this, some classes have an interface of `ref class MyClass`, which I believe is for C# legibility.

Anyway, any help would be brilliant.

Comment: `SomeType^` is a C++/CLI managed pointer. That isn't C++.

Comment: Neither of these is really C++ at all. They're C++/CLI or perhaps C++/CX (or possibly the older "Managed C++"). Every few years, Microsoft invents a new language based on C++, but with extensions for their "managed" environment (.NET). So far, none of these has gained much popularity (to put it mildly).

Comment: This might be related: [Should we use _In_ instead of __in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093053/should-we-use-in-instead-of-in)

Comment: as he mentions Metro, I'd say that that's part of C++/CX for WinRT...

Comment: `^` is _not_ a pointer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is a [SAL annotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383(v=vs.110).aspx), used for code analysis.  The annotations themselves are defined as macros that, in normal builds, expand to nothing.

The `^` and `ref class` are features of [C++/CX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699871(v=vs.110).aspx), a set of language extensions developed to make it easier to build Metro style apps for Windows 8 in C++.  Neither is a part of standard C++.  The documentation (linked previously) has links to tutorials and references describing the language extensions.

Comment: Perfect answer, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**In *sal.h* file o found this definition**

```
// Input parameters --------------------------

//   _In_ - Annotations for parameters where data is passed into the function, but not modified.
//          _In_ by itself can be used with non-pointer types (although it is redundant).

// e.g. void SetPoint( _In_ const POINT* pPT );
#define _In_                            _SAL2_Source_(_In_, (), _Pre1_impl_(__notnull_impl_notref) _Pre_valid_impl_ _Deref_pre1_impl_(__readaccess_impl_notref))
#define _In_opt_                        _SAL2_Source_(_In_opt_, (), _Pre1_impl_(__maybenull_impl_notref) _Pre_valid_impl_ _Deref_pre_readonly_)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (from a quick google) that the `_in_` is there to indicate if a parameter is an input or output (`_out_`) to a function/method.

The `^` is a managed pointer (garbage collected pointer, related to C++/CLI).

Comment: Ha, I thought that said `ln`, not `in`. That's indeed the purpose with Microsoft.

Comment: @DeadMG Actually, [it is a reference _handle_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699870.aspx), **not** a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

`_Out_` means argument passed as reference. `_In_` means the opposite. `(_Out_ x)` and `(&x)` are similar.