# What do "_in_" and "_in_opt_" mean in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm fairly new to CLR, I'm reading the c++/CLI documentation for setWindowPos and the function is defined like so.

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowPos(
  _In_      HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  _In_      int X,
  _In_      int Y,
  _In_      int cx,
  _In_      int cy,
  _In_      UINT uFlags
);
```

I have experience in c++ so I understand that, for example, "HWND" is the data type and "hWnd" is the variable name.

But what are "**_***in*_" and "_in_opt_"?

I'm guessing they're short for "input variables" or something.

It is mentioned in the documentation that the hWndInsertAfter is optional. Does this mean I can simply omit/not bother passing a variable to to this parameter in my function call if I don't need to?

e.g.

```
SetWindowPos(this,0,0,GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMAXIMIZED),GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMAXIMIZED),SWP_NOZORDER);
//Note that we're one parameter short here (the second is missing)
```

(This would be confusing to me, as I've seen it written in other places that C++ does not support optional parameters. Only default parameters and overloading)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is \_In\_ in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457328/what-is-in-in-c)

Comment: Yes, i just located this similar topic. I'll admit that my initial research was not good enough, sorry. However, the answer I got from this question was a touch more relevant to my specific questions.

Answer (score 21):

This is part of Microsoft's [`Source-Code Annotation Language`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx). `_In_Opt_` means you may pass `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now that I have a name for these annotations (I originally thought that they were interpreted and meant something significant to the compiler), I have a starting point for further research.

Comment: _In_opt_  (opt is all lower case!)